# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline vendor/assets folder organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, vendor

I'm using the [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/) scrollable library in my Rails 3.1 site with the various assets placed in the vendor/assets folder and it works great.

My question is regarding the best way to organize the various files under vendor/assets.  What is the recommended way to organize vendor/assets subfolders?  Currently I have this structure:

```
vendor/assets/
 |-- images/
 |    |-- scrollable/
 |          <various button/gradient images>
 |-- javascripts/
 |    |-- scrollable/
 |          jquery.tools.min.js
 |-- stylesheets/
 |    |-- scrollable/
 |          scrollable-buttons.css
 |          scrollable-horizontal.css
```

This is a fairly un-DRY what to do this.  I feel that all of the 'scrollable' items should be under one folder.

What is the recommended way to do this without having to manipulate the asset pipeline load paths?

Thanks!

Comment: It has a benefit, though. All your images, stylesheets and javascripts are grouped in their own folders and not scattered acrossa a dozen of plugins.

Comment: one plugin in multiple directories is hard to manage. Removing or updating it would be a pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could organise them this way, which is slightly better in that it keeps stuff related to the plugin in one directory:

```
vendor/assets/scrollable
 |-- images/
 |    |-- <various button/gradient images>
 |-- javascripts/
 |    |-- jquery.tools.min.js
 |-- stylesheets/
 |    |-- scrollable-buttons.css
 |        scrollable-horizontal.css
```

I am pretty sure this will work as rails globs all directories under assets/.

Comment: For the life of me I can't get this to work.  I've structured my vendor/assets like this, but when I do something like:  //= require scrollable/jquery.tools.min I get a Sprockets::FileNotFound  error.  How else would I require that?

Comment: Try adding `javascripts` into the path

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798646/what-are-the-best-practices-when-organizing-assets-in-rails-asset-pipeline