# Rails3 and static assets of CSS+Javascript in plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, static-libraries, asset-pipeline, assets

I have downloaded some plugins that contains multiple .css,.js and image files, is there a way for me to circumvent splitting each of these plugins up into these three directories:

- app/assets/stylesheets
- app/assets/javascripts
- app/assets/images

Is there a way I can put all three types of files into a vendor-folder, and use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763914/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-vendor-assets-folder-organization) of a similar question. The short answer though is that regardless of location you are still doing the three folders (images, stylesheets, javascripts) though you would do them like this `vendor/assets/plugin_name/` and then the three. This post here expands on the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798646/what-are-the-best-practices-when-organizing-assets-in-rails-asset-pipeline) a bit.